# 505 Access is Denied in uploading file in FTP server

Tags: java, android, ftp-client

I really need help on this one. I cannot upload file to a folder in ftp server. I don't know what is wrong with my codes. I tried other ways to upload but nothing works. Below is my my code:

```
            client.connect(Constants.FTP_ADDRESS);

            result = client.login(Constants.FTP_USERNAME, Constants.FTP_PASSWORD);

            if (result == true) {
                System.out.println("Successfully logged in!");
                client.changeWorkingDirectory(Constants.FTP_FOLDER_UPLOAD);
                String _reply = client.getReplyString();

                Log.i("REPLY CODE CHANGE WORKING DIRECTORY", _reply);

                for (int i = 0; i < l_arraylist_file.size(); i++) {
                    File file = new File(l_arraylist_file.get(i).toString());
                    String testName = file.getName();
                    Log.i("FILENAME", testName);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                    // Upload file to the ftp server
                    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                    boolean a = client.storeFile(testName, fis);
                    String reply = client.getReplyString();
                    Log.i("REPLY CODE UPLOADING", String.valueOf(reply));

                    if(a){
                        System.out.println("File is uploaded successfully");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("File uploading failed");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

It log for REPLY CODE UPLOADING returns 505 Access is Denied. I don't know what's wrong or if there's a missing line in my code.

UPDATE:

Code above is already working. The permission on the FTP server folder is the problem. It needs to be set in full permission.

Comment: Try to give full permission to folder and server file.

Comment: @felix can I do that programmatically? or I need to directly do that on the server folder?

Comment: Directly set permission.

Comment: You could have started telling the type of your client. Which class is it?

Comment: @greenapps its FTPClient

Comment: @felix it's already in full permission.

Comment: Is not there a storeFile() that uses a filePath instead of an input stream? Try to use that one. Place setfiletype and setpassivemode after changeworkingdirectory or before.

Comment: @felix yes the permission on the ftp server folder is the problem, not in my codes. Thank you for the idea.